# How to control the space between header of 'Nomenclature' and first line?

Tags: nomenclature, vspace, nomencl

I use `\printnomenclature` to generate my list of abbreviations. Unfortunately, the first line is directly underneeth the header. I had a similar issue with LOF and LOT and was able to get rid of the issue by adding `\addtocontents{log}{\vskip 1em}` and `\addtocontents{lot}{\vskip 1em}`.

[image]

It would be great if one of you could help.
Thx